# Metatag module version 7.x-1.4 generates Meta tags vertical tab disappears

Tags: 7, updating, nodes

When I updated my contributed module Metatag to the last version some problems happened.
Meta tags vertical tab element disappears from new node creation menus. It seems there is some issues with database and new elements.

Anyone knows something about it?

Drupal core version: 7.34

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like a bug in module, and bugreports are not on-topic here.